# How can I upgrade to the new Instagram messaging inside of Europe?

Tags: instagram, gps, instant-messaging

It's so annoying that all my friends can react to messages with any emoji and reply to messages, while I can't. It would make messaging so much more convenient. They disabled these features in the EU for some stupid privacy reasons.

I'm in Europe now, and I tried all of these (at the same time):

- used VPN to use internet through Thailand
- set fake GPS location to Thailand
- temporarily switched to my Thai SIM Card
- updated phone number associated with Instagram account to my Thai phone number
- even cleared app data of Instagram app before opening it again

And still I didn't get the option to upgrade my messaging.

Even when I was in Thailand last year I couldn't update it.

Does anyone know a way to bypass this?

Edit:
Even after linking my Instagram and Facebook accounts, and repeating all the above steps, I still don't get the option to update it.

Comment: Questions about applications for mobile devices such as the [Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/) or [iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) are [off topic](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for Web Applications.

Answer (score -1):

it's because your account was created in a region wich this feature isn't possible

Comment: oh that makes sense, thank you (btw it's not me who downvoted your answer)